# Is it wrong to have answer which containing most of the data from other site with its reference?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

As per comment on my [answer](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9755/do-they-really-drink-or-eat-when-shooting-movies) , i got confused about the use of copied content.
As per old meta [post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/use-of-copied-content), i though using a copied content is ok till i mention the source and done my own effort too. I want to know that is this answer is ok or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its not 'wrong' per se, if you comply with the other sites requirements for using their material (as you reference in the meta post in this question).  You will never see me close or complain to you about such an answer.  You've done some research and found another site which answers the question.

However (in my opinion), your answers where you are just copying large sections from Wikipedia or TV-Tropes is not adding a great deal.  It is better than just posting a link to the other site, but in my opinion not much better.

It would (IMHO) be better if you summarize in your own words a direct answer to the question based on the research you have done, and link to any references you have.

Comment: One thing I would like to say is that sometimes it is askers fault. The direct Wikipedia link has such a lucid writing that there is no more need than merely copy and post the content.

Comment: But why read a whole page when someone can summarize it for you in 3-4 sentences?

Comment: I have tried to improve the question, deleted unnecessary junk but still some examples are too good to be altered