# What is the duration of temporary ban on editing?

Tags: support, editing

What is the duration of temporary ban on editing or suggesting edits? I have been temporarily banned from suggesting new edits as most of my suggestions were rejected. How can this ban be lifted from my account? I think my edits were rejected because they were tag wiki excerpts which were copied from the net directly and not in my own words I did not know about this rule so I edited the tags and got banned. How can I recover my editing rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the duration of temporary ban on editing or suggesting edits?

Currently, it's 7. From this [main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192/321725),

> No, but repeated edit suggestion rejections from multiple users will cause your edit suggestion rights to be suspended for (n) days, where n is currently 7.

Looks like you have suggested 12 edits and half of them were rejected. That's 50-50. Since you're banned on March 28th, and it's April 4th, so the ban should be over anytime soon (I see @Iandotkelly has removed it now).

**Approved Edits:**

1. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72842
2. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72843
3. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72841
4. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72801
5. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72786
6. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72784

**Rejected Edits:**

1. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72846
2. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72847
3. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72787
4. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72788
5. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72785
6. https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/72783

IMO, even 2 edits among approved ones are also not worth approval.

> How can this ban be lifted from my account? How can I recover my editing rights?

I am not sure if moderators can lift the ban. There is no meta post I could find regarding this. So, I'd suggest that you should at least wait for the ban to lift and then make good edit suggestions that improve posts ([but avoid trivial edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214892/321725)).

Try to follow the rules for suggested edits. You can start from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/321725). And for the current tag wiki edits, see [this post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/752/27264)

Answer (score 2):

The ban will clear in 6 hours according to the details that I (as a moderator) can see.  I don't know what rules are applied to set the ban length - but that is the situation as of now.

The ban length is set automatically I believe, but moderators can unban you.

Since you have noticed why the edits were rejected I will unban you now.

Comment: Well, 7 days are about to over now.

Comment: @AJ ...ha, I didn't notice that the ban had almost gone its entire duration of 7 days!