# Cannot update tag information

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I saw there's few tags still has no usage guidance. so I tried to update some. after two (I think), every tag I tried to update shows below message.

One section with this:

> There is no usage guidance for this tag … yet!
>
> Usage guidance, also known as a tag wiki excerpt, is a short blurb that describes when and why a tag should be used on this site specifically.

Another section with this:

> There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!
>
> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its usage.
>
> All registered users may propose new tag wikis.
>
> (Note that if you have less than 20000 reputation, your tag wiki will be peer reviewed before it is published.)

I'm not sure it's for me or it's for everyone. last one I tried is for insidious tag, [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/tags/insidious/info).

Why is this happening?

Comment: I see lot of you tag description are pending for approval.

Comment: @AnkitSharma yes, didn't know about the limit, thats why :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on Propose Tag info button under Tag Wiki. You will be redirected to update tag wikis and tag excerpts.

If more than 5 edit suggestions are pending, then your edit suggestions will not be taken into consideration. As of writing, there are 6 edit suggestions pending. From [Complete rate limiting guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/357396)

> At most 5 pending suggested edits per editor (20 on beta sites)

From [Rate limiting suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202/357396):

> > As of a few seconds ago, this limit is now active network-wide:
>
> - at-most 20 pending suggested edits per editor on beta sites
> - at-most 5 pending suggested edits per editor on graduated sites

So, wait till the reviews are completed and then suggest new tag excerpts and wikis.

As a general suggestion for everyone, **[Please do not suggest copied tag wikis or excerpts](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/752/48608).**

Comment: Oh.. didn't know about the limit. Thanks :)